# elasticsearch -- getting right query string

Tags: python, elasticsearch, django-1.9

i am new to elasticsearch and currently looking for distance query on results of query_string: Here is my code:

```
doc = {
        "query": {
            "query_string": {
                "query": term,
                "fields": ['name', 'business_name', 'email', 'city',
                   'state', 'zip_code', 'business_keywords', 'phone_number',
                   'address', 'country'
                ], 
            }, 
            "filter": {
                "geo_distance": {
                    "distance": radius, 
                    "distance_unit": "km", 
                    "distance_type": "arc", 
                    "location": {
                        "lat": latitude, 
                        "lon": longitude
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
search_response = client.search(index="b",body=doc)
```

but i am getting the following error  :

RequestError: TransportError(400, u'search_phase_execution_exception', u'failed to parse search source. expected field name but got [START_OBJECT]')
Any idea ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to combine your `query_string` and `geo_distance` queries into a bool query.

```
doc = {
        "query": {
          "bool": {
            "must": {
              "query_string": {
                "query": term,
                "fields": ['name', 'business_name', 'email', 'city',
                   'state', 'zip_code', 'business_keywords', 'phone_number',
                   'address', 'country'
                ], 
              }
            }, 
            "filter": {
                "geo_distance": {
                    "distance": radius, 
                    "distance_unit": "km", 
                    "distance_type": "arc", 
                    "location": {
                        "lat": latitude, 
                        "lon": longitude
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for answering. can you tell me from where to read elasticsearch from scratch

Comment: The official documentation would be a good place to start: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index.html

Comment: How to define GeoPointField() in elasticsearch django. It shows a serialization error. i am using library "django_elasticsearch_dsl"

Comment: Why did you change your question? My answer doesn't make any sense now. I've reverted your changes.

Comment: can you please tell me the answer if you know

Comment: Link for other question --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50617543/how-to-serialize-django-instance-before-save

Comment: i don't know how to close a question