# How to serialize Django GeoPt for Elasticsearch

Tags: python, django-1.9, elasticsearch-dsl

How to define GeoPointField() in elasticsearch django. It shows a serialization error when i am trying to save the instance. i am using library "django_elasticsearch_dsl
code:

```
from django_elasticsearch_dsl.fields import GeoPointField
geolocation = GeoPointField()
```

when i am trying to save the data

```
 user = GutitUser.objects.get(phone_number=phone_number)
 lat, lon = get_lat_long()
 user.geolocation.lat = lat
 user.geolocation.lon = lon
 user.save()
```

it shows error:

```
 "Unable to serialize <django_google_maps.fields.GeoPt object at 0x7f5ac2daea90>
 (type: <class 'django_google_maps.fields.GeoPt'>
```

get_lat_long method

```
def get_lat_long(request):
    ip = json.loads(requests.get('https://api.ipify.org?format=json').text)['ip']

    lat, lon = GeoIP().lat_lon(ip)
    return lat, lon
```

Comment: Can you show the `get_lat_long()` method too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `django_elasticsearch_dsl` (and further, `elasticsearch_dsl`) doesn't know how to serialize that custom `django_google_maps.fields.GeoPt` object into a format understood by Elasticsearch.

Quoting the [docs](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html), the object will need to have a `to_dict()` method.

> The serializer we use will also allow you to serialize your own objects - just define a `to_dict()` method on your objects and it will automatically be called when serializing to json.

You should be able to monkey-patch that method in with something like (dry-coded)

```
from django_google_maps.fields import GeoPt

GeoPt.to_dict = lambda self: {'lat': self.lat, 'lon': self.lon}
```

early in your app's code (an AppConfig `ready()` method is a good choice, or failing that, a `models.py`, for instance)

Comment: now it shows error -->  TransportError(400, u'search_phase_execution_exception', u'failed to find geo_point field [geolocation]')

Comment: That means your Elasticsearch index doesn't contain that field.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `get_lat_long()` returns an object of type `django_google_maps.fields.GeoPt` and you cannot assign is to your `geolocation` object. But modifying the code like below might do the trick:

```
 user = GutitUser.objects.get(phone_number=phone_number)
 geo_point = get_lat_long()
 user.geolocation.lat = geo_point.lat
 user.geolocation.lon = geo_point.lon
 user.save()
```